# Netbeans IDE 7.0 Web Application Doesn't Support Java EE 6 Out of the Box?

Tags: java-ee-6, vs-web-application-project, netbeans-7

I just downloaded and installed the newest Netbeans IDE 7.0 Java EE edition (with Tomcat and GlassFish servers).  Oddly enough, when I create a Web Application through the New Project wizard, the "Servers and Settings" step doesn't have an option for Java EE 6 in the "Java EE Version" pull-down menu, all I see is Java EE 5 and J2EE 1.4!

This is especially bizzare because the only other Java IDE I use is Netbeans 6.9.1 and even *that* one had Java EE 6 configurable right in the drop down.

Does anyone know how I can add Java EE 6 support to this wizard in Netbeans 7.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*facepalm*

My mistake. The reason EE 6 wasn't populating in the drop-down was I had accidentally selected an older version of the Apache Tomcat server which in fact did not support EE6. Selecting Tomcat 7.0.11 solved this problem.